# Transform other irreducible polynomials from an irreducible polynomial.

Tags: reference-request, irreducible-polynomials

By experimenting I found what seems to be true for polynomials in $\mathbb Z[X]$:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i$ is irreducible iff $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n b_iX^i$ is irreducible, where $b_{2\cdot j}=a_{2\cdot j}$
and $b_{2j+1}=\pm a_{2j+1}$.

I don't remember if I have seen this along time ago or not. I want a link or something.

Comment: Sounds like Dumas's criterion? "A polynomial $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$ with integer coefficients is irreducible if and only if the polynomial $g(x) = b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_nx^n$, where $b_{2j} = a_{2j}$ and $b_{2j+1} = \pm a_{2j+1}$ for $0 \leq j \leq n/2$, is irreducible."

Comment: I only have a link to the "Polynomials" by Prasolov. https://math.ru/lib/files/pdf/prasolov/poly.pdf c.7.1.

Comment: @rumathe - Thank you!

Comment: To be clear, $x^3 + x^2 + 3x + 1$ is irreducible, while $x^3+x^2-3x+1$ is reducible, so this is only true if the $\pm$ signs are all the same.

Comment: @BenjaminWright - You are right, it was a delusion.